# Are SQL where conditions executed for each row?

Tags: sql

If I have a query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE (value & (POW(2, 24) - 1) > 0;
```

Will query engines generally execute `(POW(2, 24) - 1)` N times, for each row in the table (assuming `value` isn't indexed)? Or is it smart enough to know that value doesn't change and to cache it and use the cached value? Does it depend on the database implementation?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, it depends on the database engine.

In general, though, databases will evaluate constant expressions during the compilation phase.  That means that a constant is inserted rather than the value being re-calculated for each row.  Depending on the database and the expression, this may not always occur.

The `where` clause will be evaluated for each row using the constant (an index cannot be used on this expression).